# fetching data from array inside json in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to get two values from a `JSON`

Content of JSON:

```
[
   {
      "type":"session_start",
      "properties":[
         {
            "property":"activity",
            "type":"string"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

to use in a component but been having trouble with getting the value of property

these are the codes I'm trying to use right now, but for some reason I get the error.

> Property 'properties' does not exist on type 'Object'.

any ideas on how to make the outcome of props be "activity" ?

```
   type = this.service.getData().pipe(map((response: any) => response.map((eventRead: { [x: string]: any; }) => eventRead['name'])));
    
   props = this.service.getData().pipe(map(p => p?.properties?.property));
```

[image: desired output:]

Comment: it's the issue of type definition. Can you share the code of "service.getData()"? Or try `map((p: any) => p?.properties?.property)`

Comment: That didn't show any errors! It still doesn't work but it might be a different part of my component :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to loop through the array of arrays, you can use `flatMap` to flatten the array of arrays inorder to get the desired output!

```js
const arr = [{
  "type": "session_start",
  "properties": [{
    "property": "activity",
    "type": "string"
  }]
}]

const service = {
  getData: () => rxjs.of(arr)
};

type = service.getData().pipe(rxjs.map((response) => response.map((eventRead) => eventRead['type'])));
console.log('type');

type.subscribe(console.log);

props = service.getData().pipe(rxjs.map(arrayData => {
  const output =  arrayData.flatMap(p => {
    if (p.properties && p.properties.length) {
      return p.properties.map(x => x.property);
    }
    return [];
  }) 
  // if you want an array output uncomment the below line!
  // return output;
  return output && output[0];
}));
console.log('props');
props.subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.5.6/rxjs.umd.min.js" integrity="sha512-yUlloKtrX4U41iKbaafsHrrwII0n1uAX9+3KzuaTjkfgLicBplGfr0vv7FtfwC5kgead1Dmr7sjunFFp0a+s9Q==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Update:

It was due to autocomplete and options being mapped incorrectly with elementRef

[working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-upvavw-awmus1)

Comment: I went through the code you sent and the only thing I see that might not work for me is that you put the array in the component which is something I cannot do. The function getData() is the one that gets the json's content so can I just use this.service here? I'm not sure if it's possible to use flatmap on an object. Other than that it seems like a light in the dark for me. TYSM NAREN

Comment: I haven't figured it out yet. my second box is still showing type. Do you mind if I send you the entire component?

Comment: @LeonardoRodrigues Could you provide a stackblitz, along with screenshots of expected output?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/github/leoquiro/Assignment?file=src/app/app.component.ts is here, how do I send you screenshots?

Comment: @LeonardoRodrigues attach to the question

Comment: done mate, you can check it out :)

Answer (score 1):

`properties` is inner array. So, you should call something like

```
props = this.service.getData().pipe(
  map(p => {
    const firstElement = p.properties.shift();
    return firstElement.property;
  })
);

props.subscribe(p => console.log(p)); // activity
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply and directly get the value of "property" through,

```
const json = [
  {
    type: 'session_start',
    properties: [
      {
        property: 'activity',
        type: 'string',
      },
    ],
  },
];

var property = json[0].properties[0].property;
console.log(property);
```

Output:

```
activity
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the optional chaining operator (?.) while accessing the properties array from the json to avoid the exception, you have to add checks for each level of the object.

if there is a single element in properties array then you can directly access the element by index like below:

```
let property = json[0]?.properties[0]?.property;
```

if there are multiple elements in properties array then you do something like below:

```
let prop = json[0]?.properties;
if(prop?.length > 1)
{
   for(let i=0;i<prop.length;i++)
   {
      //You can access the property data element here.
      console.log(prop[i].property);
   }
}
```